# Is there a name for this polynomial theorem?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

I came across this question:

> Let $P$ be a polynomial with real coefficients and $z$ be a complex number. It is known that $P(z) = 2 + i$, what is the value of $P(\overline{z})$.

The answer is $2 - i$, which just on first glance seems like some combination of the remainder theorem and the conjugate root theorem, but I have no idea if this is a known theorem with a name, or how to go about proving it, but from testing a bunch of examples, it seems to be the case that in general if $P(z) = a + bi$, then $P(\overline{z}) = a - bi$. Does anyone have a proof for this, or know what this is called?

Comment: It works like this because conjugation is an automorphism of the complex numbers which fixes the real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a polynomial with real coefficients $P(\bar{z})=\overline{P(z)}$.

Let $$P(z)=a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+\cdots+a_nz^n,\ a_i\in\mathbb{R}$$
Then $P(\overline{z})=a_0+a_1\overline{z}+a_2\overline{z}^2+\cdots+a_n\overline{z}^n$.

Now $z=re^{i\theta}$ for $r=|z|$ and $\theta=\arg(z)$. Then $\overline{z}=re^{-1\theta}$. Hence $\overline{z^k}=\overline{re^{ik\theta}}=re^{-ik\theta}=\overline{z}^k$. Thus we have $$\overline{z^k}=\overline{z}^k\ \ \forall\ z\in\Bbb{C}$$.
Also $$\overline{cz}=c\overline{z}\ \ \forall\ z\in\Bbb{C},c\in\Bbb{R}$$
And finally $$\overline{z_1+z_2}=\overline{z}_1+\overline{z}_2$$
Combining these three results we get $$\overline{a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+\cdots+a_nz^n}=a_0+a_1\overline{z}+a_2\overline{z}^2+\cdots+a_n\overline{z}^n$$

Answer (score 0):

It is just as you said a simple corolaly. $a\bar z^n=\overline{az^n}$, for any real $a$ ,(if $a$ is real then note that $\overline a=a$). Now add the monomials and you have what you need.